# list timeline and count overlap

Tags: mysql, timeline

I have the following sample data set...

```
CREATE TABLE timeline (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
s_t DATETIME,
e_t DATETIME,
quantity INT(3)
);

INSERT INTO timeline
(`id`,`name`, `s_t`, `e_t`, `quantity`)
VALUES
(NULL, "joe", "2021-01-15 10:00:00", "2021-01-15 14:00:00","1"),
(NULL, "joe", "2021-01-15 15:00:00", "2021-01-15 18:00:00","1"),
(NULL, "joe", "2021-01-15 19:00:00", "2021-01-15 21:00:00","1"),
(NULL, "frank", "2021-01-15 10:00:00", "2021-01-15 14:00:00","1"),
(NULL, "frank", "2021-01-15 13:00:00", "2021-01-15 18:00:00","1"),
(NULL, "frank", "2021-01-15 19:00:00", "2021-01-15 21:00:00","1"),
(NULL, "bob", "2021-01-15 10:00:00", "2021-01-15 14:00:00","1"),
(NULL, "bob", "2021-01-15 15:00:00", "2021-01-15 18:00:00","1"),
(NULL, "bob", "2021-01-15 19:00:00", "2021-01-15 21:00:00","1"),
(NULL, "harry", "2021-01-17 14:00:00", "2021-01-17 17:00:00","1"),
(NULL, "harry", "2021-01-17 10:00:00", "2021-01-17 15:00:00","1"),
(NULL, "harry", "2021-01-17 08:00:00", "2021-01-17 11:00:00","1");
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a126a50d9a612bb1603e381d65a3a734

I am trying to get SUM of 1 PER NAME when there is no overlapping times and a SUM of 2 or more when there are overlapping times.
(There doesn't need to be a "note" column - that's just to illustrate my point.)

| id | name | start | end | total | *note* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | bob | 2021-01-15 10:00:00 | 2021-01-15 14:00:00 | 1 |  |
| 9 | bob | 2021-01-15 19:00:00 | 2021-01-15 21:00:00 | 1 |  |
| 8 | bob | 2021-01-15 15:00:00 | 2021-01-15 18:00:00 | 1 |  |
| 4 | frank | 2021-01-15 10:00:00 | 2021-01-15 14:00:00 | 2 | *overlap* |
| 5 | frank | 2021-01-15 13:00:00 | 2021-01-15 18:00:00 | 2 | *overlap* |
| 6 | frank | 2021-01-15 19:00:00 | 2021-01-15 21:00:00 | 1 |  |
| 12 | harry | 2021-01-17 08:00:00 | 2021-01-17 11:00:00 | 2 | *overlap* |
| 11 | harry | 2021-01-17 10:00:00 | 2021-01-17 15:00:00 | 3 | *2 overlaps* |
| 10 | harry | 2021-01-17 14:00:00 | 2021-01-17 17:00:00 | 2 | *overlap* |
| 1 | joe | 2021-01-15 10:00:00 | 2021-01-15 14:00:00 | 1 |  |
| 2 | joe | 2021-01-15 15:00:00 | 2021-01-15 18:00:00 | 1 |  |
| 3 | joe | 2021-01-15 19:00:00 | 2021-01-15 21:00:00 | 1 |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following...

```
SELECT x.*
     , COUNT(*) total 
     , GROUP_CONCAT(y.id) overlaps
  FROM timeline x  
  JOIN timeline y 
    ON y.s_t <= x.e_t 
   AND y.e_t >= x.s_t 
   AND y.name = x.name
 GROUP 
    BY x.id;
+----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+-------+----------+
| id | name  | s_t                 | e_t                 | quantity | total | overlaps |
+----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+-------+----------+
|  1 | joe   | 2021-01-15 10:00:00 | 2021-01-15 14:00:00 |        1 |     1 | 1        |
|  2 | joe   | 2021-01-15 15:00:00 | 2021-01-15 18:00:00 |        1 |     1 | 2        |
|  3 | joe   | 2021-01-15 19:00:00 | 2021-01-15 21:00:00 |        1 |     1 | 3        |
|  4 | frank | 2021-01-15 10:00:00 | 2021-01-15 14:00:00 |        1 |     2 | 4,5      |
|  5 | frank | 2021-01-15 13:00:00 | 2021-01-15 18:00:00 |        1 |     2 | 5,4      |
|  6 | frank | 2021-01-15 19:00:00 | 2021-01-15 21:00:00 |        1 |     1 | 6        |
|  7 | bob   | 2021-01-15 10:00:00 | 2021-01-15 14:00:00 |        1 |     1 | 7        |
|  8 | bob   | 2021-01-15 15:00:00 | 2021-01-15 18:00:00 |        1 |     1 | 8        |
|  9 | bob   | 2021-01-15 19:00:00 | 2021-01-15 21:00:00 |        1 |     1 | 9        |
| 10 | harry | 2021-01-17 14:00:00 | 2021-01-17 17:00:00 |        1 |     2 | 10,11    |
| 11 | harry | 2021-01-17 10:00:00 | 2021-01-17 15:00:00 |        1 |     3 | 11,12,10 |
| 12 | harry | 2021-01-17 08:00:00 | 2021-01-17 11:00:00 |        1 |     2 | 12,11    |
+----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for taking a look. The data is correct EXCEPT for #8. It should be on 2021-01-15 too. Update is below. My results in my query are wrong. I want the results to look like the table above... id 1,2,3 doesn't have any overlaps, so each quantity should be 1. We are not comparing joe to frank to bob, etc., just comparing each person to themselves. ...
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=11c6916efb138dfdb40002ec953fb431

Comment: Nowhere in your question do you mention that rather salient fact :-(. Edited.

Comment: Sorry. I thought it was made clear in the table. I understand it wasn't. I am going to update the original post and I appreciate you pointing out I could have been clearer. I do really appreciate your help.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow your code, but it does seem to give me the exact result I want. Thank you!

Comment: The rule for overlaps is as follows: Event A overlaps Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends, and ends after Event B starts. All my query does is test for that, by joining the table to itself, and comparing start and end dates.

Comment: Makes sense now. Thank you again.